# Solving Hackerank's anagram solution in ruby

Tags: ruby, anagram

```
def anagram(s)
  counter = 0

  if s.length.even?
    splitter = s.chars.each_slice(s.length / 2).map(&:join)
    left = splitter[0]
    right = splitter[1]
    return 0 if right == left

    counter = left.length

    leftchar = left.split
    rightchar = right.split

    rightchar.each do |n|
      leftchar.each do |m|
        counter -= 1 while n == m
      end
    end
    counter
  else
    return -1
  end
end
```

> Hello, I am trying to solve a problem in [Hackerank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/anagram/problem) in ruby. The program
>   is to return the number of characters to be changed in a string that has been split so as to match the other string. That is if the word is not an anagram in itself.

So far:

- I am checking first if the string is even first before splitting the
  string into two, otherwise, the program should return -1.
- Next, after splitting the string, I am trying to check if there could
  be a character present in the right string not present on the left string. And since my program is to return the number of characters
  needed to be changed, for every character found in the left present
  in right, I minus one from the left's length.

That's how my logic is. But I seem to be missing out on something. is there any suggestions and heads-up I can get from this? Thanks.

Comment: `counter -= 1 while n == m` loops forever if `n==m`. (There are more issues.)

Comment: Other issue: `split` splits on whitespace. Use `split("")` or `chars` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the many ways to do this is the following.

```
def min_nbr_swaps(str)
  return -1 unless str.size.even?
  half = str.size/2
  str1 = str[0,half]
  str2 = str[half,half] 
  h = str2.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  str1.each_char.count do |c|
    case h[c]
    when 0
      true
    else
      h[c] -= 1
      false
    end
  end
end
```

```
min_nbr_swaps('aaabbb')   #=>  3
min_nbr_swaps('ab')       #=>  1
min_nbr_swaps('abc')      #=> -1
min_nbr_swaps('mnop')     #=>  2
min_nbr_swaps('xyyx')     #=>  0 
min_nbr_swaps('xaxbbbxx') #=>  1
```

The steps are as follows.

```
str = 'xaxbbbxx'
```

```
str.size.even?
  #=> 8.even? => true, so do not return -1
half = str.size/2
  #=> 4 
str1 = str[0,half]
  #=> "xaxb" 
str2 = str[half,half] 
  #=> "bbxx" 
h = str2.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument called the default value. All that means is that when Ruby's parser expands `h[c] += 1` to

```
h[c] = h[c] + 1
```

`h[c]` on the right returns `h`'s default value, 0, if `h` does not have a key `c`. For example, when `h` is empty,

```
h['x'] = h['x'] + 1 #=> 0 + 1 => 1
h['x'] = h['x'] + 1 #=> 1 + 1 => 2
```

`h` does not have a key `'x'` in the first expression, so `h[c]` on the right returns the default value, `0`, whereas `h` does have that key in the second expression so the default value does not apply.

Continuing,

```
enum = str1.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "xaxb":each_char>
```

We now use the method [Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) to determine the number of characters in `str1` that need to be modified.

```
enum.count do |c|
  case h[c]
  when 0
    true
  else
    h[c] -= 1
    false
  end
end
  #=> 4
```

The first element passed to `count`'s block is `str1[0] #=> 'x'`.

```
c = 'x'
```

As `h['x'] #=> 2`, the `case` statement executes

```
h['x'] -= 1
```

and returns `false`, meaning that `x` need not be changed. Now `h #=> {"b"=>2, "x"=>1}`

Next, the block variable is assigned the value `str1[1] #=> 'a'`:

```
c = 'a'
```

As `h['a'] #=> 0`, the `case` statement returns `true`, meaning `a` needs to be changed. Here `h[a]` returns the *default value*, `0`, because `h` has no key `a`. `h` is not changed.

The remaining calculations are similar, all returning `false`. `count` returns `1` because the block returns `true` for only `1` of the `4` characters in `str1`.

Comment: Neat solution, but not sure how `h[c]` could be `nil` with a default of `0` applied.

Comment: @tadman, a belated thank you for your observation, which caused me to correct my answer all those many moons ago.